# Expand background color beyond margin in css

Tags: html, css

I1m currently working on a personal website but I have no experience with web development so I got stuck at a functionality that probably has a very simple solution. I have many of this div on my page and I just wanted the greyed background to:

1. Expand just a few pixels beyond the content of the div
2. Have rounded borders

[image]

I'm currently using

```
background-color: #ffffffab;
background-clip: content-box
```

to get the results shown, but either I paint ALL of the div, which is not what I intend to do or I leave it as it is shown in the picture. When using "border-radius" I have to increase to huge numbers like 80% to get rounded edges, and even so it cuts some part of the text. Is there an easy way to do what I'm trying to do? I'm also including this picture with the margins (orange) and padding (green).

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: wrong approach. Try paddings and simpyl a border-radius

Answer (score 0):

Following @tacoshy suggestion:
I added more margin to the top and bottom of the container and increased the padding on the sides, this way I wouldn't need to use the content-box function: `margin: 2em auto 2em; padding: 2em`.

That solved it.
Thanks!